# Why this folder with a strange name appears on my laptop?

Tags: windows-10, security, filesystems

I am uncomfortable with a folder that appeared on my laptop. I feel that it treats my data. I would like to know what it is exactly and how to get rid of it. Thank you so much for your help.

[image: Folder with strange name]

Comment: Run `chkdsk` to verify the disk.

Comment: Does the folder with the strange name also exists on your Desktop?

Comment: Run an offline scan with Windows Defender (offline is in the WD settings) . See if that quarantines the file.

Comment: Run regedit, then search for `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree`.  The icon should provide a clue as to what it is.  In fact, I'd probably review Control Panel > Uninstall a Program and look for that icon.  Perhaps even try doing a reverse image search of that icon, as well.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, in fact, `chkdsk` took me almost 2 or three 3 hours and the offline scan with Windows Defender went on all day. Unfortunately, the problem did not solve yet. The windows do not report any threats with `chkdsk` and the offline defender has shown a prompt with a scan results, I quickly clicked `OK` and moved to see if the `"file"` steel there, and yes! it is always there.
I can see the so-called File only where I took the screenshot. It is not in the Desktop or the Program list.

Comment: Thank you a lot @leeharvey1 , by using your hint, I got more information about what it is exactly. I changed each value of `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` under `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in `regedit` to `0` to see if it will disappear or not until I found it in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{1870nder 1C81-34AB-498E-8C7F-5D26B9C36732}`. Bref, this folder was created after I installed `Baidu Net disk` program.

Comment: `after I installed Baidu Net disk program` .. are you kidding?

Comment: what's the matter ?

Comment: Baidu is made in china and transmits personal user data to Baidu servers without encryption and with easily decryptable encryption, Their code is vulnerable to arbitrary code execution during software updates via man-in-the-middle attacks.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I found some interesting courses in bilibili and the creators share some interesting files on pan*baidu*com---since those files will enormously help me I took the risk, but I found that after installing the program that I can download them directly in oneleaf*icu 
Thank you for your advice I appreciate...